# Is there a way to change volume of sounds in Pygame Zero?

Tags: python, volume, pgzero

I'm working on fully fleshing out a game I made following a tutorial, and have been trying to incorporate sound effects into the finished thing. However they are way too loud and I can't seem to find a way to quieten them. I know there's a way in normal pygame but I don't know if there's one for pgzero. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Here's a snippet of code in case that helps:

```
if gem.colliderect(ship):
        sounds.gem_collect.play()
        gem.x = random.randint(20, 1180)
        gem.y = 0
        score = score + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used pygame zero. But here is [the documentation](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html?highlight=play()#sounds). Doesn't say anything about setting volume for sound objects, but you can `set_volume()` for music:

> music.set_volume(volume)
>
> Set the volume of the music system.
> This takes a number between 0 (meaning silent) and 1 (meaning full volume).

You could try to use the `set_volume()` method on a sound object and see what happens. Maybe it's just not documented well.

```
if gem.colliderect(ship):
    sounds.gem_collect.set_volume(0.2)
    sounds.gem_collect.play()
    gem.x = random.randint(20, 1180)
    gem.y = 0
    score = score + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pygame zero's documentation I didn't found  a way to control volume using `sounds` but you can change it in `Music`.

```
if gem.colliderect(ship):
        music.play_once(track_name) # you don't need to add track extenstion in it
        music.set_volume(num) # num is any number between 0 (meaning silent) and 1 (meaning full volume)
        gem.x = random.randint(20, 1180)
        gem.y = 0
        score = score + 1
```

**Attention**
This Music api is experimental and have it's own drawbacks and is only availbale in 1.1 and after. Some of the Drawbacks

- MP3 may not be available on some Linux distributions.
- Some OGG Vorbis files seem to hang Pygame with 100% CPU.

more about Music in pygame zero [link](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/builtins.html#music)